# Starting Native application from web application in Tizen wearables

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I want to create a tizen wearable application where I can invoke the native service from tizen web application on button click. 
I have been finding this for the past week, but could not get round this issue. Can anyone help me with the code?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried message port communication?

Comment: Did you try it ?

Comment: A lot of resources are available which can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I found this from [here **Receiving Bundle from Native App**](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/receiving-bundle-native-app#answer-comment).

Service Code

```
#include <tizen.h>
#include <service_app.h>
#include <bundle.h>
#include <message_port.h>
#include "messageportnativeservicesend.h"

#define TAG "xyz"

void
sendMessage(char *remote_app_id,char *remote_port,bundle *reply){

    int ret = message_port_send_message(remote_app_id, remote_port, reply);

    if (ret != MESSAGE_PORT_ERROR_NONE)
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, TAG, "message_port_check_remote_port error: %d", ret);
    else
        dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, TAG, "Send message done");

    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, TAG, "Send message was called");
}

void
test_check_remote_port(char *remote_app_id,char *remote_port,bool result)
{
    int ret;
    ret = message_port_check_remote_port(remote_app_id,remote_port,&result);
    if (ret != MESSAGE_PORT_ERROR_NONE)
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, TAG, "message_port_check_remote_port error: %d", ret);
}

void msgPort()
{
    char *remote_app_id="mRLmiKfKmV.MessagePortWebReceiver";
    char *remote_port="CrossPort";
    bool result;

    test_check_remote_port(remote_app_id,remote_port,result);
    dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, TAG ,"Remote port exists: %s", result ? "true" : "false");

    bundle *reply;
    reply=bundle_create();

    char *array[] = {"XY","YZ","ZX","AB"};

    bundle_add_str(reply,"test","A");
    bundle_add_str_array(reply,"service",array, 4);

    dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, TAG, "Bundled Successfully");


    if (result){
        sendMessage(remote_app_id,remote_port,reply);
        bundle_free(reply);
    }

}

bool service_app_create(void *data)
{
    msgPort();
    return true;
}

void service_app_terminate(void *data)
{
    // Todo: add your code here.
    return;
}

void service_app_control(app_control_h app_control, void *data)
{
    // Todo: add your code here.
    return;
}

static void
service_app_lang_changed(app_event_info_h event_info, void *user_data)
{
    /*APP_EVENT_LANGUAGE_CHANGED*/
    return;
}

static void
service_app_region_changed(app_event_info_h event_info, void *user_data)
{
    /*APP_EVENT_REGION_FORMAT_CHANGED*/
}

static void
service_app_low_battery(app_event_info_h event_info, void *user_data)
{
    /*APP_EVENT_LOW_BATTERY*/
}

static void
service_app_low_memory(app_event_info_h event_info, void *user_data)
{
    /*APP_EVENT_LOW_MEMORY*/
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char ad[50] = {0,};
    service_app_lifecycle_callback_s event_callback;
    app_event_handler_h handlers[5] = {NULL, };

    event_callback.create = service_app_create;
    event_callback.terminate = service_app_terminate;
    event_callback.app_control = service_app_control;

    service_app_add_event_handler(&handlers[APP_EVENT_LOW_BATTERY], APP_EVENT_LOW_BATTERY, service_app_low_battery, &ad);
    service_app_add_event_handler(&handlers[APP_EVENT_LOW_MEMORY], APP_EVENT_LOW_MEMORY, service_app_low_memory, &ad);
    service_app_add_event_handler(&handlers[APP_EVENT_LANGUAGE_CHANGED], APP_EVENT_LANGUAGE_CHANGED, service_app_lang_changed, &ad);
    service_app_add_event_handler(&handlers[APP_EVENT_REGION_FORMAT_CHANGED], APP_EVENT_REGION_FORMAT_CHANGED, service_app_region_changed, &ad);

    return service_app_main(argc, argv, &event_callback, ad);
}
```

Web Code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // TODO:: Do your initialization job

    // add eventListener for tizenhwkey
    document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
        if(e.keyName === "back") {
            try {
                tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
            } catch (ignore) {
            }
        }
    });



    /* MessagePortCallback instance */
    function onReceived(data, remoteMsgPort) {
        console.log("Local port Listener Called");

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var keyX = data[i].key;
            console.log("key:" + keyX);

            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].value.length; j++){
                var valueX = data[i].value[j];
                console.log("value:" + valueX);        
            }
       }

    }

    function messagePort(){
         var localPort = tizen.messageport.requestLocalMessagePort("CrossPort");
         localPort.addMessagePortListener(onReceived);
         console.log("Local port Listener Registered");
    }

    // Sample code
    var textbox = document.querySelector('.contents');
    textbox.addEventListener("click", function(){
        messagePort();
        var box = document.querySelector('#textbox');
        box.innerHTML = (box.innerHTML === "Basic") ? "Sample" : "Basic";
    });

};
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to develop a "Hybrid" tizen application.
As per tizen.org

"The Tizen platform allows you to create hybrid application packages, which combine a Web UI application and 1 or more native service or widget applications."

There is also a sample application to do this.
[Hybrid Sample App](https://developer.tizen.org/development/sample/web/Hybrid/Hybrid_Web_App)

Here is more information on how to package it.
[Tizen Hybrid Applications](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/packaging-hybrid-application)